# node js + express + ejs. Cannot read property 'option0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

app.js

```
var options = { option0: 11, option1: 'option1', option2: 'option2', option3: 'option3', option4: 'option4', option5: 'option5', option6: 'option6', option7: 'option7', option8: 'option8', option9: 'option9', option10: 'option10', }

res.render('main', {opt : options});
```

main.ejs

```
<select class="form-control" name="selected" required>

    <% for (let i = 1; i < opt.options.option0; i++) { %>
        <% optionName = 'option' + i %>
        <option value="<%= i %>"><%= opt.options[optionName] %></option>
    <% } %>

</select>
```

ERROR: Cannot read property 'option0' of undefined.

Comment: `opt` *is* `options` when the page is rendered, so `opt.options` tries to find `options` inside `opt` which doesn't exist. `opt.option0` alone should do (and `opt[optionName]` too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed the `options` as a reference object for the property opt.So `opt` will now point to `{ option0: 11, option1: 'option1', ...}` and your render function becomes

`res.render('main', {opt : { option0: 11, option1: 'option1', ...}});`

So when you try to access `opt.options.option0` , `opt.options` becomes undefined and throws error

Thus you should be using
`

```
<% for (let i in opt) { %>
    <% optionName = 'option' + i %>
    <option value="<%= i %>"><%= opt[i] %></option>
<% } %>
```

`