# Error cannot read property of undefined Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, ejs

I am currently learning to build a blog website using Node.js, Express and ejs
I got the following error when I try to render the "show" page
I found a similar problem here but there is a different usage of my code, I still couldn't get mine solved.
[The similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408725/node-js-express-ejs-cannot-read-property-option0-of-undefined)

I did also had an same type error earlier says "cannot read property 'username' of undefined" , but after I restart the server it gives me a different error.

The error I got now:

```
TypeError: C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\MyBlog\views\blogs\show.ejs:22
20| 

21|             <div class="text-muted">

22|                 <%= blog.date.toLocaleDateString()%> By <%= blog.author.displayName %>  **<------**

23|             </div>

24|         </div>

25|
```

Cannot read property 'toLocaleDateString' of undefined

Portion of router.js:

```
//show the specific blog
router.get("/home/:slug", async(req, res) => {
    const blog = await Blog.find({ slug: req.params.slug });
    console.log(blog);
    if (blog == null) {
        res.redirect("/home");
    }
    res.render("blogs/show", {blog: blog});
})
```

Portion of show.ejs

```
    <div class="card-header">
        <h1 class="mb-1"> 
            <%= blog.title %>
            <a href="/home" class="btn btn-light btn-sm float-right"><i class="fas fa-home fa-lg"></i></a>
            <!-- Override DELETE method -->
            <form action="/home/<%= blog.id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST" class="d-inline">
                <% if((currentUser) && (currentUser.username === blog.author.username)){ %> 
                    <a href="/home/edit/<%= blog.id%>" class="btn btn-light btn-sm float-right"><span class="far fa-edit fa-lg"></span></a>
                    
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-sm float-right"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i></button>
                <% } %> 
            </form>
        </h1>


        <div class="text-muted">
            <%= blog.date.toLocaleDateString()%> By <%= blog.author.displayName %> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

I checked that the blog object is saved into the database correctly:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4722cc1a623a7710871d6d"),       
    "author" : {
            "id" : ObjectId("5f47177faa8e6e3e4c80f3e9"),
            "username" : "333@gmail.com",
            "displayName" : "Jacky Chan"
    },
    "date" : ISODate("2020-08-27T03:04:44.646Z"),       
    "title" : "1321321321321",
    "coverImg" : "",
    "contents" : "<p>3213131321321321</p>",
    "slug" : "1321321321321",
    "sanitizedHtml" : "<p>3213131321321321</p>",        
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I used console.log in the ejs file and it seems that it did found the correct blog....

[image: result from console.log]

I am guessing that the blog object is referenced incorrectly, maybe?

Finally I don't know if it is the problem of async/await but I tried all I can which eventually lead me here...
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**Update 1:**
Thanks to @AdamExchange
I tried the answer from @AdamExchange that switched `find()` to `findOne()`.
The previous error is gone but there is a new error that when I use my create new blog route, it is calling the show route and trying to find the blog.

New Error:

```
TypeError: C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\MyBlog\views\blogs\show.ejs:9
7|         <div class="card-header">
8|             <h1 class="mb-1">
9|                 <%= blog.title %>
10|                 <a href="/home" class="btn btn-light btn-sm float-right"><i class="fas fa-home fa-lg"></i></a>
11|                 <!-- Override DELETE method -->
12|                 <form action="/home/<%= blog.id %>?_method=DELETE" 
method="POST" class="d-inline">

Cannot read property 'title' of null
```

My question is why would the show route get involved when I use the GET method on create routes? (I do have a button on the create blog page that uses the show route)

Here I will post my entire router hopefully that will help:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router({mergeParams:true});
const Blog = require("../models/blog");
const middleware = require("../middleware");


router.post("/home", (req, res, next) => {
    req.blog = new Blog();
    next()
}, saveBlogAndRedirect('new'))

router.get("/home/new", middleware.isLoggedIn, async(req, res) => {
    let blog = new Blog();
    res.render("blogs/new", { blog : blog });
})


//Get the blog with the correctid

router.get("/home/edit/:id", async(req, res) => {
    const blog = await Blog.findById(req.params.id);
    res.render("blogs/edit", { blog : blog });
})


router.put("/home/:id", async(req, res, next) => {
    req.blog = await Blog.findById(req.params.id);
    next()
}, saveBlogAndRedirect('edit'))

//show the specific blog
router.get("/home/:slug", async(req, res) => {
    const blog = await Blog.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug });
    if (blog == null) {
        res.redirect("/home");
    }
    res.render("blogs/show", {blog: blog});
})


router.delete("/home/:id", async(req, res) => {
    await Blog.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    res.redirect("/home");
})

function saveBlogAndRedirect(path){
    return async(req, res) => {
        let blog =  req.blog;
        blog.title = req.body.title;
        blog.coverImg = req.body.coverImg;
        blog.contents = req.body.contents;
        blog.author = {
            id : req.user._id,
            username: req.user.username,
            displayName: req.user.displayName
        }
        try{
            blog = await blog.save();
            res.redirect(`/home/${blog.slug}`);
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            res.render(`blogs/${path}`, { blog : blog });
        }  
    }
}

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I think typo in ```res.render("blogs/show", {blog, blog});```, it should be like ```res.render("blogs/show", {blog:blog});```

Comment: Oh man good catch! But the same problem still exists after I corrected that....

Comment: a similar problem happened to me, in my case I passed commented stuff in the body of the request through postman & parser wasn't able to parse it. `JSON cannot have comments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const blog = await Blog.find({ slug: req.params.slug });`

Will return an *array* of the blogs with that slug. If you know there is only one, you can change it to `.findOne`. The array of blogs is getting passed to the ejs template as blog (noted by your screenshot

```
[
   {
      author: ...
    }
]
```

The 'date' property of the array is meaningless, but if you make sure to only pass your ejs template one blog object, that should fix it

Comment: I got another problem when I use find One on my create route......which it says: cannot read property "title" of null

Comment: it means your result from findOne is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code for, it will also work if the number of document is more than one. Since you are using `find()` method it will return all the document with matching filter.

Router

```
//show the specific blog
    
router.get("/home/:slug", async(req, res) => {
  const blog = await Blog.find({ slug: req.params.slug });
  console.log(blog);
  if(blog == null) {
     res.redirect("/home");
  }
  res.render("blogs/show", {blog:blog});
});
```

ejs section

```
<% for(var i=0; i<blog.length; i++){ %>

   <div class="card-header">
       <h1 class="mb-1"> 
          <%= blog[i].title %>
          <a href="/home" class="btn btn-light btn-sm float-right"><i class="fas fa-home fa-lg"></i></a>
                <!-- Override DELETE method -->
                <form action="/home/<%= blog[i].id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST" class="d-inline">
                    <% if((currentUser) && (currentUser.username === blog[i].author.username)){ %> 
                        <a href="/home/edit/<%= blog[i].id%>" class="btn btn-light btn-sm float-right"><span class="far fa-edit fa-lg"></span></a>
                        
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-sm float-right"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i></button>
                    <% } %> 
            </form>
         </h1>
    
       <div class="text-muted">
         <%= blog[i].date.toLocaleDateString()%> By <%= blog[i].author.displayName %> 
       </div>
   </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you but this answer doesn't do the thing I want it to do. I do want exactly one blog info shows on 1 page, and this code won't give the content of the blog which probably because that find() returns an array of objects and it didn't reference the blog content correctly